# How Print DynamoDB Query Results Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to print my query results after I have made a query to my DynamoDB table. I am going to have it display in a table later, but for now I just want to make sure it is working correctly. The query works and doesn't have any errors. I think It has something todo with the Pagination function that I don't understand. I tried reading the documentation, but it hasn't helped me.

```
 func queryWithPartitionKeyAndSortKeyAndFilterWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: (response: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    let objectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()
    let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()

    queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#userId = :userId AND #genre < :genre"
    queryExpression.filterExpression = "#author > :author"
    queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = [
        "#userId": "userId",
        "#genre": "genre",
        "#author": "author",
    ]
    queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [
        ":userId": AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().identityId!,
        ":genre": "fiction",
        ":author": "Taylor",
    ]

    objectMapper.query(Books.self, expression: queryExpression, completionHandler: {(response: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            completionHandler(response: response, error: error)
        })
    })
}


let completionHandler = {(response: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        var errorMessage = "Failed to retrieve items. \(error.localizedDescription)"
        if (error.domain == AWSServiceErrorDomain && error.code == AWSServiceErrorType.AccessDeniedException.rawValue) {
            errorMessage = "Access denied. You are not allowed to perform this operation."
        }
    }else {


        print("I did it" )
        print(response)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput` has a property called [`items`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput.html#//api/name/items). You should print out the content of the array.

Comment: That worked! I used print(response!.items) and it printed out the output so I am happy.